# Android Studio: How to add line break in git commit message?

Tags: git, android-studio, git-commit

When inserting the git commit message, how can I add a line break? Writing another message on a new line doesn't have the effect and the 2 messages are shown in one line on the site (Bitbucket).

I know I can achieve this with command line, but what about here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that [markdown isn't supported in commit message on GitHub and BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Can+I+use+markup+in+commit+messages?focusedCommentId=598841430#comment-598841430), so the issue doesn't come from the Git hosting services.

Maybe the issue comes from how Android Studio interpret the commit message, like as a [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) source:
Try and add 2 spaces at the end of first line, to see if the message will end up with a intermediate newline or not.

Comment: It seems you're right. Android Studio can't interpret the message correctly (at least the way I expected). In the push window, my commit message is shown in one line. Also, adding 2 spaces wasn't effective.